# Run Gradle tasks from Intellij

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I normally run Gradle tasks (xx.sh files) in cygwin and am wondering if I can run them from my IDE, Intellij. I have installed the BashSupport plugin, but have no idea how to create a bash launch configuration. A kind, step-by-step instruction would be appreciated since I am super new.

Also, can someone tell me what is good/bad about running tasks from Intellij instead of from cygwin?

Comment: [IntelliJ supports Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html).

Comment: Thank you @nkr !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IDEA supports Gradle. For a start, you should install the Gradle plugin if you haven't done this. Then you need a `build.gradle` and import the project as Gradle project.

About this

> A kind, step-by-step instruction would be appreciated since I am super new.

Well, [there is no such thing as a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch). Do what everyone else does: Read the documentation and learn. @nkr gave you the first hint. Don't expect people to do your job.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @halirutan, I had already checked pretty many pages before asking but still was not sure if I should re-import the whole project as Gradle project and was worried to mess something up by re-import.

Comment: Make a copy of your whole folder an try it on the copy first then. When my memory serves me right, you can import the project as Gradle project and IDEA recognizes that you already have a `.idea` settings folder inside the project. It asks if it should overwrite it. I'm not sure if answering this with "no" will still do the right thing and leave your settings alone. Once you have a Gradle project, you can run and build (doesn't make much sense with bash scripting) like you would normally do and the actions are forwarded to the Gradle tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the tips @halirutan, as soon as I made a copy, the original project started complaining on the packages it could not recognize (Error: "package xxx does not exist") here and there even after rebuilding it. Could this be related to the copied project? I have not done anything to the copy yet.

Comment: It is really hard to say something without sitting in front of your computer. You could check the "Project Settings" if you had relative paths to libraries that are no longer correct after you copied the project. In general, a project should be set-up that it is independent of the folder it is in.

Comment: This is supposed to be an answer useful for the people, it is reported by search engines and people come here to find information, everything someone find is an arrogant presumptuous criticism for a legit question (remember this website is the first source of information for programmers).

Comment: If you have read the comments above, then you should acknowledge that arrogance was absolutely no intention of mine. However, simply repeating what can be found in the [docu](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) or on the Jetbrains site makes no sense. And in its essence, it is as simple as I have described in my answer. When you have a working Gradle built, you can simply import it as Gradle project and you can start all tasks from within IDEA.